# <Unknown ssid> on android 12 even though location is enabled

Tags: java, android, network-monitoring

I am trying to implement a network monitor that will get the ssid of the wifi network connected.

```
                public void onCapabilitiesChanged(Network network, NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities) {
                    super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities);
                    // NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
                    WifiInfo wifiInfo = (WifiInfo) networkCapabilities.getTransportInfo();
                    String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
                    if (network != null && networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                        if (ssid.startsWith("\"") && ssid.endsWith("\"")) {
                            Log.v(M_TAG, "ssid had quotations");
                            ssid = ssid.substring(1, ssid.length() - 1);
                        }
                        Log.v(M_TAG, ssid);
```

I have granted all location-wise permissions on runtime by default for my app and I have enabled location GPS on the device but still I am getting  from the wifiINfo.getSSID().

Any ideas?

im also passing the FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO in my networkcallback:

```
networkCallback =
            new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback.FLAG_INCLUDE_LOCATION_INFO)
```

Comment: I get also this for my package:

W LocationManagerService: location noteOp with location off

Which is strange since I have pregranted all locations and enabled location on UI.